# Can i use duplicate webview in one stack screen?

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview, react-native-video

In my a stack screen, I have used two library of webview system. The one is 'react-native-video', other is 'react-native-youtube-iframe'.

The problem is that each library conflicts. When the crash occurred, there were no error messages.

When entering the screen, Vimeo and YouTube play for about a second and then stop at the same time. Originally, it should be auto-play.

If only one library is used on one screen, it will play normally.

Below is my example code.

```js
const Screen = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Vimeo  // import Vimeo from 'react-native-video'
          {/*...settins*/}
      />

      <YoutubePlayer   // import YoutubePlayer from 'react-native-youtube-iframe'
           {/*... settings*/}
      />
    </View>
  )
}
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Try to get the logs using `add logcat`.

Comment: @Rohit thank you. But there are no logs about my problem